# Use json as a data source when creating an Angular Tree Control

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am using [Angular Tree Control](https://github.com/wix/angular-tree-control) to build a tree and I would like to use a json file as the data source.

This is my HTML tag

```
<treecontrol class="tree-classic"
     tree-model="treedata"
```

And this is my javascript code to get the json file as an object

```
var JSON;
$.getJSON('data.json', function(response){
    JSON = response;
    alert(JSON.property);
 });
 $scope.treedata = JSON;
```

The path should be correct (there is only two files for my test, an `index.html` and the `data.json` both in the same folder). If I take the content of my json file and I simply paste it in a variable to get the object, it works. But when I read the file, the alert says that my `JSON` variable is empty.

Would you have an idea on how to fix this? Thank you very much.

---

Update

Following the idea of callbacks, I found this solution.

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function(response){
    $scope.$apply(function() { 
         $scope.treedata = response;
    });
});
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: why `alert(JSON.property)` is used. why not just `alert(JSON)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning `$scope.treedata` before `$.getJSON` completed. You should do it in success callback:

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function(response){
   $scope.$apply(function() { 
      $scope.treedata = response;
   });
});
```

You could use `$scope.$apply` in order to update bindings, but it is better to use `$http` service instead of `$.getJSON`

```
$http.get('data.json').then(function(response){
    $scope.treedata = response.data;
});
```

Don't forget to inject `$http` first

Comment: I tried but only got an empty tree. It seems the tree got the data correctly, but it does not show up. But it show up if I give it a json object. :S

Comment: I've added some informations. The callback helped, but it was not enough. Is there a way to do better than my `$scope.$apply`?